# Login function using SQLCommand

Tags: c#, function, authentication

I am having prob when execute the code below. when my username and password true, i will get this message "Invalid User! Try again with VALID username and password". if i enter false username n password, nothing happens(still cannot proceed to next form).

```
private bool CompareStrings(string string1, string string2)
    {
        return String.Compare(string1, string2, true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0 ? true : false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try 
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Server = blabla; Database = MoinMoun; User Id = Aema; password = 12345";
            con.Open();

            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username,password FROM Admin WHERE username='" + txtusername.Text + "' and password='" + txtpassword.Text + "'", con);SELECT ISNULL(username,'') AS username, ISNULL(password,'') AS password FROM Admin WHERE username = '" + txtusername.Text + "' and password='" + txtpassword.Text + "'", con


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username,password FROM Admin WHERE username='" + txtusername.Text + "' and password='" + txtpassword.Text + "'", con);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            string usertext = txtusername.Text;
            string passtext = txtpassword.Text;

            while(dr.Read())
            {

                if(this.CompareStrings(dr["username"].ToString(), usertext) &&
                    this.CompareStrings(dr["password"].ToString(), passtext))
                {
                    Form2 frm = new Form2();
                    frm.Show();
                    this.Hide();                        
                }
                else
                {       
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid User! Try again with VALID username and password");                        
                }
            }
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not create your query by appending text from user input to query itself, use SqlParameter to use values for query.

Comment: than you for your reply. but can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    try
    {
        con.ConnectionString = "Server = blabla; Database = MoinMoun; User Id = Aema; password = 12345";
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username,password FROM Admin WHERE username=@userName and password=@passWord", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userName", txtusername.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@passWord", txtpassword.Text));
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            con.Close();
            dr.Close();
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            frm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid User! Try again with VALID username and password");
        }
        if (!dr.IsClosed)
            dr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Since you are already comparing the username and password in the query itself, you do not need to check it again.

Use `SqlParameter` to validate user input before executing the query, it can prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also always try to close your connections to DB as early as possible. You need to free up the resource usages. Try to close the connection in finally block to ensure connection is closed before leaving the try block.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
 SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
                             {
                                 new SqlParameter("@username", txtusername.Text),
                                 new SqlParameter("@pwd", txtpassword.Text)
                             };
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username,password FROM Admin WHERE username=@username and password=@pwd", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree I would move to the sql parameters solution as well and I would also trim your input text as well of any extra white space with the trim method.

I also  think more information is needed such as the compareStrings method code.  I would use the .equals() method or String.Compare() when comparing your strings.  For instance

```
Usertxt.equals(dr["username"].ToString());
String.Compare(usertxt,Dr["username"].ToString(),false);
```